# Laser Filter and Hector Mapping Issue

Tags: slam, navigation, rplidar, laserscan, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I recently implemented the `angular_bounds_filter` from the `laser_filters` package to hector SLAM for map building. I decided to limit my RPLidar A2 laserscan from 360deg to 180deg. However, by doing so, when I launch Hector mapping, there seems to be a high tendency of drift and multiple warnings of `SearchDir angle change too large`while I see my frame on RVIZ jump around. All this happens while my robot is stationary. Is there a reason why this is happening? This particular filter is also not documented on the `laser_filters` wiki page too .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255216/laser-filter-and-hector-mapping-issue/) by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-06-08**:
Hi! any update on this issue? i seem to have same issue and warning `SearchDir angle change too large`

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-06-13**:
Hi, it actually depends on what sensor you are using and the sensor range. I realized that for a 360deg sensor, this error rarely occurs unless the sensor is shifted very abruptly, However, as the sensor range decreases, this probability of the error occurring increases.

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-06-15**:
I am using 360deg as well, now I understand what you mean by sensor range, I was trying to run the hector_mapping on the table and this error occurs. When I finally mounted the RPLIDAR on my robot and run in quite spacious rooom, it maps quite good enough. Thanks for your update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
even tho this question is little old, I had the same SearchDir warning and couldn't find something helpful. I solved the problem now and I hope I can help other people by sharing my solution:

probably your **tf to scanmatch is too slow**
(static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id **period_in_ms**)
and you simply have to set a lower value for **period_in_ms** than before, e.g.

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_scanmatcher_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map scanmatcher_frame 5"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Goldie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31552/goldie/) with karma: 31 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0